# intercept and block clicks at one view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a uiscrollview that fills the screen, at the bottom there's an imageview that is more like a dock bar at the bottom.
Right now when the user clicks on the imageview at the bottom it triggers events on the scrollview, how can I block that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the userInteractionEnabled property of the image view to true. You can do that in interface builder or in code (in viewDidLoad),

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: thnx, simple and quick, I know there's a hittest and point method but I wanted exactly what you suggested, easy solution.